# How to call a function that gives a url, which is then used to store and display an image using FileReader

Tags: javascript, dom, local-storage

I am new to coding in javascript, I have been tasked as an excersise using some pre-existing functions to create an image item using a given url. I need to read the image, store it in local storage and then display it on the screen. The only functionI need to add too is process file. I am stuck and cannot get it to display the image. I get an error saying that the path does not exist. Below is my code, any guidance to what I am doing wrong? I feel like I am very close but doing something funamendatly wrong.

```
function addImageEntry(key, url) {
    var imgElement = new Image();
    imgElement.alt = "Photo entry";
    imgElement.src = url;
    addSection(key, imgElement);
}

function makeItem(type, data) { 
  var itemObject = { type: type, data: data }; 
  return JSON.stringify(itemObject);
}

function processFile(event) {
    function addImage(url) {
        var key = "diary" + Date.now();
        addImageEntry(key, url);
        var imgElement = new Image();
        imgElement.src = url;
        var item = makeItem("image", imgElement.src);
        localStorage.setItem(key, item);
    }

    var inputElement = event.target;
    var fileObject = inputElement.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load",addImage);
    url = reader.readAsDataURL(fileObject);
    event.target.value = "";
}
```

Comment: I just edited the above to create a new variable but I get the same error. I can't seem to allocate the url

Comment: ƒ makeItem(type, data) {
    var itemObject = { type: type, data: data };
    return JSON.stringify(itemObject);
So var item becomes "{"type":"image","data":"file:///C:/Users/Name/Documents/[object%20ProgressEvent]"}"
This throws an error as not existing.

Answer (score 0):

The `url = reader.readAsDataURL(fileObject)` won't store the image data.

It stores in `reader.result`.

Use `imgElement.src = reader.result`.

```
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', processFile)

function processFile(event) {
  var fileObject = event.target.files[0]
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.addEventListener('load', addImage)
  reader.readAsDataURL(fileObject)
  
  function addImage() {
    var imgElement = new Image()
    imgElement.src = reader.result
    document.body.append(imgElement)
  }
}
```

Amend:

```
function addImage(event) {
    // use reader.result is ok too
    localStorage.setItem('myimage', event.target.result)
}

function addImageEntry() {
  var imgElement = new Image()
  imgElement.src = localStorage.getItem('myimage')
  imgElement.style.display = 'block'
  document.body.append(imgElement)
}
```

Comment: Ok this is another step closer, I think it's because I am duplicating what addImageEntry does,
I added the funtion to the original question. Currently the image is outside the section, and once the page is refreshed goes within the section.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. Are going to store the image data in a localStorage and show it from localStorage? If so, the reader.result type is string, you can just store it in the localStorage and use it.